# Display count of unique values in MySQL db table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have a table named pins that has 3 columns that need to be taken into consideration.  These columns are plan and order_id.

I need to get a count for all of the pins that have an order_id=0 and plan=9.

This is what I have so far:

```
$qT="SELECT plan, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM pins WHERE order_id=0 and plan=9";
$res=mysql_query($qT);<br/>
mysql_free_result($res);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {<br/>
echo $row['plan'];<br/>
}
```

Any help in displaying the results would be a great help.

Comment: You shouldn't be using mysql_* it is deprecated. You can look into PDO or mysqli_* which will help you out, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: The columns are 3, you post only plan and order_id. The other column is?

Comment: The other column is pin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to group your pin using `GROUP BY`, So

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT plan, COUNT(pin) as cnt FROM pins WHERE (order_id=0 and plan=9) GROUP BY plan");

echo "<table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse'>";  
echo "<th>Plan</th><th>Count</th>";  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))   
{  
   echo "<tr><td>".$row['plan']."</td><td>".$row['cnt']."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";        
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: @user3241520, answer edited as per your `pin` column, let me know it works for you or not?

Comment: Almost there!  This is what was displayed: Plan: 9 Count: 1Plan: 9 Count: 1Plan: 9 Count: 1

Comment: figured it out... Just changed the GROUP by pin to GROUP by plan.  I now get Plan: 9 Count: 3   Thank you!